# Variance of the Barvinok estimator for Hafnians of nonnegative matrices

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, determinants

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2m \times 2m}$ be a symmetric matrix with nonnegative entries. There is an [approximate algorithm](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/(SICI)1098-2418(1999010)14:1%3C29::AID-RSA2%3E3.0.CO;2-X) for estimating the Hafnian of such a matrix. Let $G$ be a skew-symmetrix matrix whose above-diagonal entries are i.i.d. random variables sampled from the standard normal distribution. Then the expected value of $\det (G \odot \sqrt{A})$ is the desired Hafnian (here $\sqrt{A}$ denotes entry-wise square root). The article in the link proves that this estimator returns the value in $[e^{-\gamma m} \operatorname{Haf} A, C \operatorname{Haf} A]$ with a high probability, where $C$ is a constant.

My question is, are there any known results about the variance of such an estimator? Or at least a bound that would enable to shrink the high-probability interval to an arbitrarily small length, like is the case with the [permanents](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/1008731.1008738) of nonnegative matrices?

Comment: maybe this fits better in https://cs.stackexchange.com/.